# Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ConcatenatingMediaSource

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I use the NuGet package Xamarin Plugin.MediaManager 1.2.2 in my iOS and Android projects but it is not working in every Android project. I have an existing Android project where it doesn't work and where I get the exception. And I have tried to create a new Android project with the same template in Visual Studio for Mac and in this new Android project I don't get the exception and the song is played. I don't know why I'm getting the exception in one Android project and not in the other. I have already tried to delete the bin and obj folders. I use the same target Android version 13.0 in both Android projects. I only know that I don't get the exception when I use Plugin.MediaManager 1.1.1.

https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager

In Activity1.cs:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
 {
       ...
       CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);
       ...
 }
```

I use this code in both Android projects and I get the exception only in one project in the second line(CrossMediaManager.Current.RepeatMode):

```
    await CrossMediaManager.Current.Pause();
    CrossMediaManager.Current.RepeatMode = MediaManager.Playback.RepeatMode.Off;
    await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://ia800806.us.archive.org/15/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3");
```

Why am I getting the exception in one project and not in the other?

Should I try to remove all NuGet packages from my project and installing all NuGet packages again?

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I only needed to remove the following code from my Android .csproj file:

```
<XamarinGoogleGuavaOptOut>true</XamarinGoogleGuavaOptOut>
```

Now I don't get the exception anymore.